# only immediate try catch is able to catch an exception

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I have weird behavior.

my client software (C# .net 4) calls some function of external dll (which was written in the same company in c#, don't have the code only dll in deployment).

During some testing I know how to get the external dll to crash (rename one of its artifact)

Here is the weird thing:
Only if I have try\catch on the immediate call in my client side - I'm able to catch it.
If I remove try\catch, and count on my BIG try\catch in application - my app is hang!! it is stuck in the call to the external dll.

now, I can add catch throw in my code but I'd like to understand why this may happen?

Comment: Difficult to say without seeing any code. Could be an intermediate catch on the way up to the BIG catch doing smthg weird with the exception.

Comment: Probably your BIG try\catch doesn't cover that call. Maybe it is executed in different thread?

Comment: thanks. My BIG try\catch is a general (Exception e)..the call is in one thread (maybe the external open other threads). the thing is that I have many logs after this action that won't happen - really hang ;)

Comment: if logs are not written - that doesn't mean it hangs. If exception happens, the code execution jumps immediately to the cacth block and doesn't even try to execute your log write calls. So it doesn't hang. Just exception is not handled. By the way, catch (Exception) doesn't catch some exception types (non-CLS compliant exceptions), but I think this is not your case. Just try adding internediate catches and find why your BIG catch isn't on the call stack when exception occurs.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that and will share if I'll have some insights on this strange behavior